# How to use the Google Calendar API from a Raspberry Pi without a keyboard?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-calendar-api, credentials

Can we get credentials for the Google Calendar API on different devices?

We are using the Google Calendar API on the Raspberry Pi with the following steps as a reference.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

We have generated the credentials by operating in the following steps
We chose TVs and Limited Input devices as the application type and then downloaded the JSON file.

Credentials > Create credentials > OAuth Client ID
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Our Raspberry Pi does not have a keyboard and display.
We note the URL displayed in "Please visit this URL to authorize this application" via ssh.
We access the URL from the PC browser and note the authentication code after tying it to the calendar.
To "Enter the authorization code" we enter it.

It works as we expect.
But this is difficult for our customers.

Can we do this authentication using a PC or smartphone?
In that case, how do we move the token.pickle from the PC or smartphone to the Raspberry Pi?
Maybe we are thinking too hard.
If there is an easier way, please tell us about it.
We just want to use the Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't have a G-Suite account use SSH in order to send the tokens

Once you get the **token.pickle** you won't need to "visit" the URL to authorize the application. Anyway, a refresh token has its restrictions. A refresh token might stop working for one of these reasons:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.

### Use a service account instead (G-Suite account only)

The **token.pickle** is generated the first time. The quickstart you mentioned makes use of the user credentials. However if you want to use just one token along the devices and see a different calendar in every device I strongly recommend you to use a service account and enable the domain-wide delegation in order to impersonate the user's calendar.

To do so:

1. [Create a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)
2. [Enable the domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
3. [Impersonate the user in order to see the desired calendar (using Python)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)

### Reference

[Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)

Comment: Thank you, Jose.
We already understand about visiting the URL only once.
Since our customers could not use SSH,
 we consulted with them about the alternatives we would offer them.
We did not know about domain-wide delegation.
We'll investigate it.

Comment: Jose, We are still trying to figure this out.
But we have yet to succeed in this.

When we use a domain delegation, can users only get schedules from that domain?
Will we only get the Google calendar information associated with G suite?
Or can any user in the world use our service?